# Выполнить ajax post запрос с параметрами используя YQL

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Необходимо выполнить ajax POST запрос с параметрами используя YQL как прокси.
Я пробую что-то в следующем виде:
<pre>

```
var url = "http://fxeuroclub.ru/rates.txt";
var q = encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="'+url+'"');
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='+q;
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: yql,
         data:'view_rates=1&sel_instr=10&time10=2014-03-18&time11=00%3A00%3A00&time20=2014-03-18&time21=01%3A31%3A08&period=1440&format=om',
         success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
          }
         });
```

</pre>

но это не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var url = "http://fxeuroclub.ru/rates.txt?view_rates=1&sel_instr=10&time10=2014-03-18&time11=00%3A00%3A00&time20=2014-03-18&time21=01%3A31%3A08&period=1440&format=om";
var q = 'select * from html where url="'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'"';
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='+q+'&format=json';
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));//полный вид возвращаемого объекта
    console.log(data.query.results.body.p);//в данном случае будет такой путь
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/HA3Wn/)

По дефолту YQL возвращает результат в xml. проще работать с json.

Comment: btw, для jquery есть плагин [Query YQL](https://github.com/hail2u/jquery.query-yql). и наверное не один....

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.