# Как получить HTML код с другого домена?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Такое дело. Мне нужно получить html код страницы с другого домена. К примеру на моем домена я должен вывести html код ссылки https://vk.com/id1 Как можно это сделать? Можно ли вообще))

Comment: На чистом js нет (точнее, только если CORS позволяет). Обычно применяют серверный хак: на сервер аяксом отдается адрес страницы, которую нужно получить, сервер ее запрашивает и отдает в ответ на аякс-запрос.

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo Query Language (YQL)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

- ХК:[Выполнить ajax post запрос с параметрами используя YQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/305542/jquery-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ajax-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-yql)
- Хабра:[Несколько находок](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135413/)